# Processing servers in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, powershell-workflow

```psh
ServiceStatus -Servers "Machine1", "machine2", "machine3" 

workflow ServiceStatus
{
    param([string[]]$servers) 

    foreach -Parallel ($server in $servers)
    {
        Write-Host "Chekcing status in  $server..." -ForegroundColor black -BackgroundColor green

        Get-Service W3SVC -ComputerName $server | Format-Table Name,Status,MachineName -AutoSize 

        if(!$?)
        {
            Out-File $FileName1 -Append -InputObject $server -Encoding ascii
        }
    }
}
```

I try to make `foreach` to execute in parallel, but it is giving me a "syntax error near foreach loop" error.

Answer (score 0):

`Format-*` cmdlets can only be used inside `InlineScript` sections in PowerShell workflows. See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions.aspx) for more information. Same goes for `Write-Host`.

Also, you must define your workflow *before* you invoke it.

```
workflow ServiceStatus {
    ...
}

ServiceStatus -Servers "Machine1", "machine2", "machine3"
```

Comment: Tried removing @Format-* and write host also. But it is still giving the same error.